# add same module into dependenices and devDependencies

Tags: javascript, module, package, babeljs, package.json

Is it possible to have @babel/core in dependencies and devDependencies object in package.json

When I `add yarn add @babel/core` it is added to dependencies, but when I do `yarn add @babel/core -D` it is not added to devDependencies.

If I delete module and do it in reverse direction, then I will add it to  devDependencies but not in dependencies.

I got this:
`warning "@babel/core" is already in "devDependencies". Please remove existing entry first before adding it to "dependencies".`

Is it possible to have same module/package in both places dependencies and devDependencies and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to have in both places?

If you put "@babel/core" in "dependencies" it will be available for both cases (for Production and Development purpose), whereas the "devDepencencies" will be available only for development purpose.

`npm install` by default installs packages from both dependencies and devDependencies.

`npm install --production` --production flag says to the npm to install packages only from usual dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that, I thought that dependencies is for production and devDepenednices for development mode.

Comment: No problem at all mate! =)
I've made a small change in my answer so if it is ok for you, upvote this one and mark as solved, please. =)